# trying to write std:out and file at the same time

Tags: c++, iostream

I am trying to write to file and stdout at the same time within c++ by overloading ofstream

test.h

```
 #pragma once 

#include <iostream>

using  std::ofstream;

class OutputAndConsole:public ofstream
{
public:
    std::string fileName;        
    OutputAndConsole(const std::string& fileName):ofstream(fileName),fileName(fileName){
    };
    template <typename T>
    OutputAndConsole& operator<<(T var);
};


template <typename T>
OutputAndConsole& OutputAndConsole::operator<<(T var)
{
    std::cout << var;
    ofstream::operator << (var);
    return (*this);
};
```

test.cpp

```
  OutputAndConsole file("output.txt");
  file << "test" ;
```

The output in the file is

```
01400930
```

but in the console is

```
test
```

I debugged the code it looks like it is entering into

```
_Myt& __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL operator<<(const void *_Val)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to do this. `Cout` and the file would have different streams, and that it...

Comment: @Link: He's inheriting the file stream, and attempting to invoke `<<` for the base.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The problem

> ```
> ofstream::operator << (var);
> ```

It's your use of `ofstream::operator<<` as a *qualified* function call. You're mandating that the function lookup locate a member function of `ofstream`; the best match that's a member is the one for `void*`, whereas the specialisation for `char*` that prints the actual string contents is a free function (i.e. *not* a member function).

You'll find the same problem if you do this with `cout`, too:

```
std::cout.operator<<(var);
```

#### The solution

This might do it:

```
static_cast<ofstream&>(*this) << var;
```

because you're still using normal operator syntax (with all the overload resolution that this entails), but doing so with an `ofstream` as the LHS operand.

I haven't actually tested it, though.

#### Conclusion

As an aside, *your* `operator<<` ought to be a free function too, in order to fit in with this convention.

So:

```
struct OutputAndConsole : std::ofstream
{
    OutputAndConsole(const std::string& fileName)
       : std::ofstream(fileName)
       , fileName(fileName)
    {};

    const std::string fileName;
};

template <typename T>
OutputAndConsole& operator<<(OutputAndConsole& strm, const T& var)
{
    std::cout << var;
    static_cast<std::ofstream&>(strm) << var;
    return strm;
};
```

I also took the liberty of making some minor syntax adjustments.

Comment: I believe the last function should be `template <typename T>
OutputAndConsole& operator<<(OutputAndConsole& os, const T& var)
{
 std::cout << var;
 static_cast<std::ofstream&>(os)<< (var);
 return (os);
};`. You're right, I was attacking the member function, instead of the global one

Comment: First of all thanks for the nice solution. For some reason to make it work (pre C++11) i had to change `std::ofstream(fileName)` to `std::ofstream(fileName.c_str())`. My problem with it is that on the console any `std::endl` and `\n`  seems to be ignored (while in the file the line breaks are fine). Do you have any idea why this is the case?

Comment: @tobi303: C++11 introduced the fstream constructors taking `std::string` so that's no surprise. As for your console, you'll have to contact technical support for your terminal emulator.

Comment: For me (MinGW-w64, Wiindows 7, running in Eclipse), flushing does not work, using this.

Comment: @xamid: What does that mean, "flushing does not work"?

Comment: It means that using `<< std::flush` or the method `flush()` do not write to the file (and thereby clear the output stream), but it should. The only working approach I found so far was using `boost::iostream::tee_device<ostream, ofstream>` of the Boost library.

Comment: @xamid: You should post your problem as a new question, being sure to include a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem. On the surface of it, there is no reason for that outcome to occur, though maybe there's something extra you have to do for I/O Manipulators that I'm missing. But you have not provided even nearly enough detail to properly diagnose the issue.

Comment: I solved the problem already by using working code from Boost. I only mentioned that your code is faulty, since it does not run properly on Windows 7, MinGW 6.4, while there is code which runs properly. If you are not interested in the correctness of your specific code, why would I?

Comment: @xamid: If I were not interested in the correctness of the code, why would I ask you twice to better explain what the problem is with it?

Comment: For me, [this testcase](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/099fafe580584490) doesn't reproduce your alleged problem (it's tough to reproduce flushing issues with 100% certainty, but adding/removing `<< std::flush` from line 35 is a pretty clear-cut test)

Answer (score 8):

I'm not going to comment on why your approach doesn't work, mainly because it cannot be patched up to work properly. The main problem is that you can't use your stream an pass it to something which expected an `std::ostream&` and still write to both streams. However, there is a relatively simple although not necessarily obvious approach to implement what you actually want: You'd derive a new stream buffer, i.e., a class derived from `std::streambuf`, and override its `overflow()` and `sync()` functions. Here is the complete code for a simple demo:

```
#include <streambuf>

struct teebuf
    : std::streambuf
{
    std::streambuf* sb1_;
    std::streambuf* sb2_;

    teebuf(std::streambuf* sb1, std::streambuf* sb2)
        : sb1_(sb1), sb2_(sb2) {
    }
    int overflow(int c) {
        typedef std::streambuf::traits_type traits;
        bool rc(true);
        if (!traits::eq_int_type(traits::eof(), c)) {
            traits::eq_int_type(this->sb1_->sputc(c), traits::eof())
                && (rc = false);
            traits::eq_int_type(this->sb2_->sputc(c), traits::eof())
                && (rc = false);
        }
        return rc? traits::not_eof(c): traits::eof();
    }
    int sync() {
        bool rc(true);
        this->sb1_->pubsync() != -1 || (rc = false);
        this->sb2_->pubsync() != -1 || (rc = false);
        return rc? 0: -1;
    }
};

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream fout("tee.txt");
    teebuf        sbuf(fout.rdbuf(), std::cout.rdbuf());
    std::ostream  out(&sbuf);
    out << "hello, world!\n";
}
```

Obviously, the creation of tee-stream could be packaged up nicely but how this looks exactly doesn't really matter. The important thing is that it is possible to create a custom destination (or source) for IOStreams and that it does not involve any attempt to inherit from `std::ostream`. The only reason to inherit from `std::ostream` (or `std::istream`) is to make the initialization of a stream with a custom stream buffer easier.

Comment: I don't know where the mistake is, but using this on Windows 7, compiled with MinGW-w64, this has the fault that once fout gets flushed, it will not write anything more to the file (after a short period of time). The program still says the fout would be open but it does not react. When only using ofstream alone, it works fine. Interestingly, the the failure does not appear when executed in eclipse, but when I run the .exe alone.